# Теги span и ul,li на одной линии

Tags: html, css, list

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день! У меня список номеров страниц. Который выглядит как на картинке сверху. Нужно чтобы стрелки налево\направо были на одной линии с цифрами. display:inline-block пробовола не помогло

```
          <div class="page">
            <div class="paginate">
              <span class="icons">chevron_left</span>
              <ul>
                <li v-for="(item, index) in numbers" :key="item+'page'">{{index+1}}</li>
              </ul>
              <span class="icons">chevron_right</span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS

```
.paginate{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 250px;
  ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  li{
    color: #264348;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    // border: 1px solid #d2d7d3;
    margin: 0 3px;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  span{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Переместите ваш код в Code Snippet, пожалуйста!

Comment: В ul вы flex применили. Что мешает также сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
    .icons {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    }
    .paginate ul li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    list-style:none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="page">
    <div class="paginate">
    <span class="icons"><</span>
    <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in numbers" :key="item+'page'">1</li>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in numbers" :key="item+'page'">2</li>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in numbers" :key="item+'page'">3</li>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in numbers" :key="item+'page'">4</li>
    </ul>
    <span class="icons">></span>
    </div>
    </div>
```